# How can I have a piece of code in Laravel that will have to run only once?

Tags: laravel, deployment, webhooks

Is there any way to make sure a piece of code runs only once? Something like DB migrations?

I have the following situation:

I changed the system so that new webhooks are attached once new user signs up. After I deploy it to the production server I wanna attach the same webhook to every existing user.

I could write an artisan command and run it manually or add it to the deployment script. But that command will only be used once. I'd prefer not to have "unnecessary" commands in my project after that.

I could also use "artisan tinker" and add my php there but that doesn't sound good keeping in mind that this is a production server.

What options do I have here?

What is the common practice?

Is there a way to have a piece of "disposable" code?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to add an event. Ie when a user signs up?

Comment: No, that one's clear. Imagine that I add an event for when user sings up that  generates a random nickname for the user. Now immediately after deployment I need to do the same for the users I already have. But this is a single time process. How am I supposed to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Ill give you an answer here as I now understand.

You have a number of ways to do this. If its a real quick diry thing you need to do why not just create a tmp controller and a route and perform your query in there. for example.

```
class UpdateController extends Controller
{
  public function users()
  {
    .. Do my SQL here
  }
}

// Routes
get('update/users', 'UpdateController@users');
```

You can run that code do you update then clean up and remove after.

Of if its a longer run process I would create an console command ie

```
app:update --flag  (maybe for method you have added).
```

the console is safer and you can run longer running process within console as your not going to time out like you would get in the browser.

For me the console command is the way to go which I have done before. You can run console commands in maintenance mode which is even better.

Hope this gives you some ideas

Comment: Thank you, but those are the cases I mentioned in my question as "possible". The problem is that this way I still add unnecessary commands/controller actions that I have to remove manually later. I was thinking about some "temporary" code holder.

Comment: You going to need to write code in any case? How are you going to be able to perform any update without any code? I have built many apps over the years and every now and then I need to perform updates. Have a console command in a ready state to add code for it helps. You can write a migration but rollback's becomes messy.

Comment: That's what my question is all about. I do understand I can add new command, run it after deployment, then delete it and deploy again. I wanna know if there's some other (better) way to be able to do that "execute once" thing without redeploying the project

Comment: I think your getting in a fluster for nothing. Lets say its a console command. You run it and thats it.. You don't have to re-deploy to remove code. You can just comment it out then on your next deploy its not longer available.. You could create a table for these like migrations you can only run it once.  Or just go down the migrations route...

Comment: So the answer is: No, there's no common practice for that. Writing and committing and deploying code that will run only once as a regular command is fine. ?

Comment: If it works then yes.. I don't think these is any need to over complicate things if you don't need to. If something needs updating how else you going to do it.. Download the data and then re-upload. I don't think so :-)

Comment: Got it. It's just...every time I do that it feels like there should be some better way. Anyway, at least now I know that others do it the same way I do and it's fine. Thank you for your time